# How to communicate b/w C# and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, maps

I'm making an application in winforms, which is supposed to load up locations from a database, and ask the user where they would like to go. the problem is that the user should be able to choose locations from google maps too. So, as the google maps api is in JS, how do i get information from it to C#?

Note: It doesn't have to be winforms, it can be wpf too

Comment: There is a browser tool where you drag and drop buttons. Then in code-behind  you can  set url and scan the result but that default browser frame may not be compatible with everything.(if it is old os)

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you simplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are just loading up locations, try to use the [Google Places Web-Service API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/). You can then make HTTP requests that will give you a response in either JSON or XML. You should then be able to use those responses to pass them to your C# implementation.

Comment: Thanks! This is a much better solution then what I was trying :)